# C++ struct selection sort not moving all variables in array

Tags: c++

I am having a bit of trouble with my selection sort and am totally stuck. The program is to create a struct "Customer" that contains 5 variables: ID name zip balance and payment date. It will be populated by user input. So far so good. Then it has to call a selection sort to sort by ID. Again so far so good. The problem I am having is when I output it, only the ID is sorted. Name, zip, balance and pay date all remain in the order they are input. How do i keep these lined up with their corresponding ID?

Here is my function....`

```
void sortCust(Customer custData[], int howmany)
{
    int k = 0;
    int minIndex;
    int minValue;
    for (k = 0; k < (howmany-1); k++)
    {
        minIndex = k;
        minValue = custData[k].id;
        for (int index = k + 1; index < howmany; index++)
        {
            if (custData[index].id < minValue)
            {
                minValue = custData[index].id;
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        custData[minIndex].id = custData[k].id;
        custData[k].id = minValue;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `std::vector<Customer>` and `std::sort()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
custData[minIndex].id = custData[k].id;
custData[k].id = minValue;
```

with

```
std::swap(custData[k], custData[minIndex]);
```

If you don't want to use STL, you could do it like this instead:

```
Customer c = custData[k];
custData[k] = custData[minIndex];
custData[minIndex] = c;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. We havent learned std::swap yet so the other worked perfectly!

Comment: You probably won't learn 75% of valuable C++ goodness in a university class.